# Moving entity between two ordered lists in eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We are using eclipselink to persist our entities. In multiple cases we have ordered lists containing the children of one entity. When moving an entity from one of those lists to the other one, we have frequent problems with an invalid order in one of those lists (gaps in the list we are moving from or duplicates in the target list).

The parent entities look like this (I have removed presumably not relevant properties, methods and annotations):

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Document implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderColumn
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
    private List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And the child entity for this case:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Row implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

}
```

To move the entity we started with this code:

```
    document.getRows().add(rowIndex, row);
    documentRepository.save(document);
```

As problems occured we first added code to remove the row from the old document:

```
    if (oldDocument != null && !oldDocument.equals(document)) {
        oldDocument.getRows().remove(row);
        documentRepository.save(oldDocument);
    }
```

For some time it also helped to change the code to save the document from `save` to `saveAndFlush` (not sure why this is the case). However this does not seem to help any longer.

These changes result in the current code:

```
    document.getRows().add(rowIndex, row);
    documentRepository.saveAndFlush(document);

    if (oldDocument != null && !oldDocument.equals(document)) {
        oldDocument.getRows().remove(row);
        documentRepository.saveAndFlush(oldDocument);
    }
```

The rows look like this in the database before doing anything:

```
id       document_id  rows_order
113940   113306       0
114041   113306       1
114044   113306       2
115671   115129       0
115674   115129       1
```

After moving the row 114041 to the document 115129 this is the resulting data:

```
id       document_id  rows_order
113940   113306       0
114044   113306       2
115671   115129       0
114041   115129       1
115674   115129       2
```

The gap in the rows_order already seems suspicious and leads to problems when inserting a new row at the end of the document:

```
@Transactional
public void addRow() {
    Document document = documentRepository.getOne(113306);
    Row newRow = new Row();
    rowRepository.save(newRow);
    document.getRows().add(2, newRow);
    documentRepository.saveAndFlush(document);
}
```

This is the error message that occurs when the transaction is committed:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_document_id_rows_order"
  Detail: Key (document_id, rows_order)=(113306, 2) already exists.
Error Code: 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
    at com.dbcentral.service.DocumentService.addRow(DocumentService.java:100)
```

`document.getRows()` is a list with two elements, so adding one element at the end should work by adding it at index 2.

We could avoid that error by removing the constraint for document_id and rows_order, however that leads to duplicate rows_order entries, looking like this:

```
id       document_id  rows_order
113940   113306       0
114044   113306       2
115676   113306       2
115671   115129       0
114041   115129       1
115674   115129       2
```

Due to ideas from the comments we tried to add the `@ChangeTracking` annotation to the Document entity. However neither of the policies seems to change anything.

Is what we are currently doing the right way to move entities between ordered lists or are we maybe missing anything?

An alternative idea is to run an sql after each of these moves, correcting the order column. Regarding this we are not sure if it is a good idea to manipulate that column while the application is running.

Comment: What issues are you getting, and what are you currently doing, exactly?  Detail the order before and after your changes, and if you have duplicates at all in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your question, I have added the data from the database before and after the operation and information about the error that occurs due to that data.

Comment: If you get rid of your constraint, does EclipseLink fix things?

Comment: After removing the constraint on document_id and rows_order inserting the new row works, however now we have duplicate values in the rows_order column, I added the resulting data to the question.

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Try using DEFERRED change tracking (or any of the others if you are already using deferred), as described here: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_changetracking.htm as I'm guessing attribute change tracking optimization is only affecting the changed entity, the row, and not realizing it must change all rows in the list.  Using a Relationship table might also work if possible.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, trying out your ideas needed some time. We had not set the ChangeTracking annotation before and neither setting it to DEFERRED nor one of the other policies did change anything.  Switching to `@JoinTable` seems to solve the order issue as far as I can see. However in that case the children of Row (annotated with `orphanRemoval = true` in their `@OneToMany` relation) are deleted while moving them. I will try to solve that issue as the next step. Thanks for your help!